# Как правильно сказать о ребенке, который посещает секцию по боксу: он увлекается боксом или он занимается боксом? Спасибо!

Tags: значение-слов

Как правильно сказать о ребенке, который посещает секцию по боксу: он увлекается боксом или он занимается боксом? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

И так и так можно, но я бы склонялся к "занимается боксом", "посещает занятия в боксерской секции/секции бокса". Увлекается боксом - разговорное, не имеет прямого отношения к занятиям в секции, может быть он увлекается просмотром боксерских боёв на ютубе - субъективная оценка, а не фактическая информация.

Answer (score 2):

Пишите правду и ничего, кроме правды (в том виде, в котором она представляется вам). Если вы считаете, что ребёнок увлечен этим видом спорта, - так и пишите. Если для вас важен сам факт, что он посещает боксёрскую секцию (безотносительно его личного отношения к этому досугу) - выбирайте второй вариант.